# How to use for loop with obj?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
Alabama:
data: (28) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
lat: "32.3182"
long: "-86.9023"
state: "Alabama"
__proto__: Object
Alaska: {state: "Alaska", lat: "61.3707", long: "-152.4044", data: Array(28)}
Alberta: {state: "Alberta", lat: "53.9333", long: "-116.5765", data: Array(2)}
```

So for each state we have soem values and `data` with values in it. One of the value inside that is `date`

I need to loop that to push to array

```
var dataSetCopy = [];
for(var t = 0; t < initialDataSet.length; ++t) {
    var eachStateData = initialDataSet[t].data;
    // this is not working > console.log(eachStateData);
    dataSetCopy.push(eachStateData.date);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```js
const formatted = data.reduce((merged, entry) => {
    const {
        // These properties will show up only once per state:
        lat,
        long,
        Province_State: state,
        // Anything else is grouped inside the `data` field for this state's entry:
        ...rest
    } = entry;

    // You can modify the `date` field here:
    rest.date = rest.date.split(' ')[0];

    if (merged.hasOwnProperty(state)) {
        // If we already added an entry for this state, simply push the other properties to `data`:
        merged[state].data.push(rest);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, add the entry for this state:
        merged[state] = { state, lat, long, data: [rest] };
    }  

    return merged;  
    }, { });

initUI(formatted);

function initUI(initialDataSet) {

    const dataSetCopy = [];
    initialDataSet.forEach(item => {
        const data = item.data; 
        data.forEach(obj => {
            dataSetCopy.push(obj.date)
        }) 
    });

    console.log(dataSetCopy);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://jikuhealth.com/wp-content/themes/JikuHealth/demo_js/united_states/5-11-20_us_states.js"></script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213659/discussion-on-question-by-rob-m-how-to-use-for-loop-with-obj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```js
const  data=[{"Province_State":"Alabama","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"32.3182","long":"-86.9023","Confirmed":"3563","Deaths":"93","Recovered":"","Active":"3470","FIPS":"1","Incident_Rate":"75.98802021","People_Tested":"21583","People_Hospitalized":"437","Mortality_Rate":"2.610159978","UID":"84000001","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"460.3001516","Hospitalization_Rate":"12.26494527"},{"Province_State":"Alaska","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"61.3707","long":"-152.4044","Confirmed":"272","Deaths":"8","Recovered":"66","Active":"264","FIPS":"2","Incident_Rate":"45.50404936","People_Tested":"8038","People_Hospitalized":"31","Mortality_Rate":"2.941176471","UID":"84000002","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"1344.711576","Hospitalization_Rate":"11.39705882"},{"Province_State":"Arizona","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"33.7298","long":"-111.4312","Confirmed":"3542","Deaths":"115","Recovered":"","Active":"3427","FIPS":"4","Incident_Rate":"48.66242224","People_Tested":"42109","People_Hospitalized":"","Mortality_Rate":"3.246753247","UID":"84000004","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"578.5222863","Hospitalization_Rate":""},{"Province_State":"Arkansas","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"34.9697","long":"-92.3731","Confirmed":"1280","Deaths":"27","Recovered":"367","Active":"1253","FIPS":"5","Incident_Rate":"49.43942261","People_Tested":"19722","People_Hospitalized":"130","Mortality_Rate":"2.109375","UID":"84000005","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"761.7533537","Hospitalization_Rate":"10.15625"},{"Province_State":"California","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"36.1162","long":"-119.6816","Confirmed":"22795","Deaths":"640","Recovered":"","Active":"22155","FIPS":"6","Incident_Rate":"58.13772584","People_Tested":"190328","People_Hospitalized":"5234","Mortality_Rate":"2.81202018","UID":"84000006","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"485.4238685","Hospitalization_Rate":"22.9611757"},{"Province_State":"Colorado","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"39.0598","long":"-105.3111","Confirmed":"7307","Deaths":"289","Recovered":"","Active":"7018","FIPS":"8","Incident_Rate":"128.943729","People_Tested":"34873","People_Hospitalized":"1376","Mortality_Rate":"3.955111537","UID":"84000008","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"615.3899908","Hospitalization_Rate":"18.8312577"}];

const dates = data.map(item => ({[item.Province_State]:item.date}))
console.log(dates)
```

or just this

```js
const  data=[{"Province_State":"Alabama","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"32.3182","long":"-86.9023","Confirmed":"3563","Deaths":"93","Recovered":"","Active":"3470","FIPS":"1","Incident_Rate":"75.98802021","People_Tested":"21583","People_Hospitalized":"437","Mortality_Rate":"2.610159978","UID":"84000001","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"460.3001516","Hospitalization_Rate":"12.26494527"},{"Province_State":"Alaska","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"61.3707","long":"-152.4044","Confirmed":"272","Deaths":"8","Recovered":"66","Active":"264","FIPS":"2","Incident_Rate":"45.50404936","People_Tested":"8038","People_Hospitalized":"31","Mortality_Rate":"2.941176471","UID":"84000002","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"1344.711576","Hospitalization_Rate":"11.39705882"},{"Province_State":"Arizona","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"33.7298","long":"-111.4312","Confirmed":"3542","Deaths":"115","Recovered":"","Active":"3427","FIPS":"4","Incident_Rate":"48.66242224","People_Tested":"42109","People_Hospitalized":"","Mortality_Rate":"3.246753247","UID":"84000004","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"578.5222863","Hospitalization_Rate":""},{"Province_State":"Arkansas","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"34.9697","long":"-92.3731","Confirmed":"1280","Deaths":"27","Recovered":"367","Active":"1253","FIPS":"5","Incident_Rate":"49.43942261","People_Tested":"19722","People_Hospitalized":"130","Mortality_Rate":"2.109375","UID":"84000005","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"761.7533537","Hospitalization_Rate":"10.15625"},{"Province_State":"California","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"36.1162","long":"-119.6816","Confirmed":"22795","Deaths":"640","Recovered":"","Active":"22155","FIPS":"6","Incident_Rate":"58.13772584","People_Tested":"190328","People_Hospitalized":"5234","Mortality_Rate":"2.81202018","UID":"84000006","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"485.4238685","Hospitalization_Rate":"22.9611757"},{"Province_State":"Colorado","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"39.0598","long":"-105.3111","Confirmed":"7307","Deaths":"289","Recovered":"","Active":"7018","FIPS":"8","Incident_Rate":"128.943729","People_Tested":"34873","People_Hospitalized":"1376","Mortality_Rate":"3.955111537","UID":"84000008","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"615.3899908","Hospitalization_Rate":"18.8312577"}];

const dates = data.map(item => item.date)
console.log(dates)
```

Dates only:

```js
const  data=[{"Province_State":"Alabama","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"32.3182","long":"-86.9023","Confirmed":"3563","Deaths":"93","Recovered":"","Active":"3470","FIPS":"1","Incident_Rate":"75.98802021","People_Tested":"21583","People_Hospitalized":"437","Mortality_Rate":"2.610159978","UID":"84000001","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"460.3001516","Hospitalization_Rate":"12.26494527"},{"Province_State":"Alaska","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"61.3707","long":"-152.4044","Confirmed":"272","Deaths":"8","Recovered":"66","Active":"264","FIPS":"2","Incident_Rate":"45.50404936","People_Tested":"8038","People_Hospitalized":"31","Mortality_Rate":"2.941176471","UID":"84000002","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"1344.711576","Hospitalization_Rate":"11.39705882"},{"Province_State":"Arizona","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"33.7298","long":"-111.4312","Confirmed":"3542","Deaths":"115","Recovered":"","Active":"3427","FIPS":"4","Incident_Rate":"48.66242224","People_Tested":"42109","People_Hospitalized":"","Mortality_Rate":"3.246753247","UID":"84000004","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"578.5222863","Hospitalization_Rate":""},{"Province_State":"Arkansas","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"34.9697","long":"-92.3731","Confirmed":"1280","Deaths":"27","Recovered":"367","Active":"1253","FIPS":"5","Incident_Rate":"49.43942261","People_Tested":"19722","People_Hospitalized":"130","Mortality_Rate":"2.109375","UID":"84000005","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"761.7533537","Hospitalization_Rate":"10.15625"},{"Province_State":"California","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"36.1162","long":"-119.6816","Confirmed":"22795","Deaths":"640","Recovered":"","Active":"22155","FIPS":"6","Incident_Rate":"58.13772584","People_Tested":"190328","People_Hospitalized":"5234","Mortality_Rate":"2.81202018","UID":"84000006","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"485.4238685","Hospitalization_Rate":"22.9611757"},{"Province_State":"Colorado","Country_Region":"US","date":"2020-04-12 23:18:15","lat":"39.0598","long":"-105.3111","Confirmed":"7307","Deaths":"289","Recovered":"","Active":"7018","FIPS":"8","Incident_Rate":"128.943729","People_Tested":"34873","People_Hospitalized":"1376","Mortality_Rate":"3.955111537","UID":"84000008","ISO3":"USA","Testing_Rate":"615.3899908","Hospitalization_Rate":"18.8312577"}];

const dates = data.map(item => item.date.split(" ")[0])
console.log(dates)
```

Comment: hey man thanks a lot. I have actually posted the snippet as we said. Also didn't know hwo to create it, so thanks for that tip too. I now try your answer

Comment: okey dokey, also remember I need to push it to the array as per the quetsion

Comment: the answer transforms directly to one array, flattening all the collected dates in data at the end.  it's already doing what you're asking for, without using push

Comment: yup works, thanks a lot. Not need that split btw, I already do it in the code rest.date = rest.date.split(' ')[0];